# htaccess reqrite from one directory to another

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What is the best practice of rewriting URL from one directory to another.
Actualy this is my folder structure.

```
/
    /folder1
        /subfolder1
            index.php
        /subfolder2
            index.php
            ...
    /folder2
        /subfolder1
            index.php
        /subfolder2
            index.php
            ...
    /folder3
        index.php
        /images
        /css
        /...
            /...
        ...
```

What I want to achieve is that only requests to `http://example.com/folderX/subfolder1/*` rewrites to `index.php` in `folder3`

I don't want to rewrite anything from subfolder2 and I need everything from subfolder1 rewrited.

So far I have this. Is it good solution or there is a better way?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*?)/subfolder1$
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ folder3/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```